# SVD library for Xcode

Tags: c, svd

I looked around for a SVD library to be used in a C-code for Xcode. I found **svdcmp.c** (from the Numerical Recipes in computing) but its very very slow. I have found other SVD libraries such as **SVDLIBC** and **CLAPACK**. But they have to be compiled by the terminal. Is there a way of compiling them in Xcode? Or there might be another library present?

Comment: Then compile them in the terminal and use Xocde to link them. Not that hard.

Comment: Yeah I know thats one way. However, I am looking if there's a way to do it in Xcode itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in xcode you can include/add the accelerate/accelerate.h framework to your project. than you have access to CLAPACK which is the c version available.  gdesvd_ is the function you are looking for.

Comment: `dgesvd_`[https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-singular-value-decomposition-lapack-driver-routines], not `gdesvd_ ` ! First symbol d/f means type of input (double/float), and then follows the name of routine.